# finding substrings of a string

Tags: algorithm, math, combinations

For a string of length n, the formula to compute all the substrings are: n(n+1)/2
Can someone help me out in intuitively understanding this formula?

Wikipedia says: 
*"The number of substrings of a string of length  where symbols only occur once, is the number of ways to choose two distinct places between symbols to start/end the substring"*

Comment: Check out this link, where they talk about the formula n(n+1)/2, for another piece of information: http://www.maths.surrey.ac.uk/hosted-sites/R.Knott/runsums/triNbProof.html

Answer (score 66, accepted):

To understand this, note that any substring needs two parameters: start index and end index.

For example: string str = "Hello World"; // length == 11

Lets begin by taking only one-character substring at time: H, e, l, l, o, , W, o, r, l, d. Then by taking 2 characters at time: He, el, ll, lo, o ,  W, Wo, or, rl, ld. Then by taking 3 chars: Hel, .. etc.

So the total substring count is 11 + 10 + 9 + .. + 1 and, in general, `for i from 1 to n`, we have `n - i + 1` substrings. By summition:

Sigma (n + 1 - i) from i = 1 to n, yields `n * (n + 1) - n * (n + 1) / 2` which is `n * (n + 1) / 2`

Comment: It's still unclear how to get n * (n + 1) - n * (n + 1) / 2 from Sigma (n + 1 - i) from i = 1 to n

Answer (score 8):

A substring is determined by where it starts and where it ends in the original string.
For any substring we have those two end points. Reversely, for any two characters in the string there is exactly one substring that starts and ends at those points.

Thus the number of all substrings is the number of all pairs of (not necessary distinct) characters.

There are `n*(n-1)/2` pairs of distinct characters. You also need to add the non-distinct pairs, which are n.

So the total number is `n * (n-1) / 2 + n = n * (n+1) / 2`.

Answer (score 8):

Well, It is the sum of all substrings of length 1 (exactly n), 
plus all substrings of length 2 (n-1), 
plus all substrings of length n (which is a proper string). Then, you have n + n-1 + n-2 ... + 1 = (n * (n+1)) / 2

The sum can be computed using natural induction and it is also known due to Gauss who solved this sum when he was at school.

Comment: did you mean n*(n+1)/2?

Answer (score 4):

A substring is defined by it's two endpoints,basically we can consider substrings as slices of a string.
Let's understand it with an example.
consider string "abc" of length 3

> a  b  c

To slice the string we have 4 positions starting from before a to the end of string after c.From these 4 available options we have to choose 2 positions to create a slice i.e a substring which is equal to <sup>4</sup>C<sub>2</sub> == <sup>n+1</sup>C<sub>2</sub>==n*(n+1)/2

Answer (score 1):

I'm no good at math, but what are `substrings` of a string and what are the possibilities to get `substrings` of a string i'll try to explain you.

lets take an example: "MOBILE" this is a string of 6 characters, now according to your formula
n(n+1)/2 which results is 6(6+1)/2=21

So the substring is any string of characters which has start index and end index between the whole string.

in string "MOBILE" following are the substring we can have :

step 1: "M" start index "M" and end index "M" this is one possibility

step 2: "MO" start index "M" and end index "O" this is second possibility

.

.

step 5: "MOBIL" start index "M" and end index "L" this is fifth possibility

.

.

step 8: "OB" start index "O" and end index "B" this is eight possibility

.

.

step 21:"MOBILE" start index "E" and end index "E" this is twenty first possibility

These are the possibilities to have a substring within a string and in substring end index cannot be less than start index.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose you want to find out substring of "abc",
that would be 
{"a","ab","abc","b","bc","c"}
we would compute it by the following code

```
for(int i=0;i<len;i++){
        for(int j=i;j<len;j++){

        }
    }
```

Looking at this code, it is easy to tell that the loops run as

> 3 times in the first run,
>   2 times in the second run,1 times in the third run

As it returns a substring everytime,therefore ***it is equal to summation of n***
that is = ***n(n + 1) / 2***